# How to reduce delay between supervisord process executions for laravel SQS queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I have done the supervisord setup with following code for the file : `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/queue-worker.conf`.

```
[program:queue-worker-callbacks]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=sudo php /var/www/backend/current/artisan queue:work sqs-plain --queue=callbacks
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/backend/shared/storage/logs/supervisord_logs.log
```

but the supervisord is taking a delay of 45 seconds between each process execution.see the log result below

```
[2021-05-16 17:11:56] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
starting job processing
done the job processing
[2021-05-16 17:11:57] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
[2021-05-16 17:12:46] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
starting job processing
done the job processing
[2021-05-16 17:12:47] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
[2021-05-16 17:13:36] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
starting job processing
done the job processing
[2021-05-16 17:13:37] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
[2021-05-16 17:14:25] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
starting job processing
done the job processing
[2021-05-16 17:14:26] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
[2021-05-16 17:15:14] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
starting job processing
done the job processing
[2021-05-16 17:15:16] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessCallbacks@handle
```

tried the
`command=sudo php /var/www/backend/current/artisan queue:work sqs-plain --queue=callbacks --timout=5 --tries=1`
also. still its taking time even though one job processing  is taking only one second. can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Is it only one server which handle the processes or there are more than one servers with the same database/redis? If there are two or more than one servers. The second job will be processed by other server and you won't see it in the first one.

Comment: @EmilGeorgiev there is only one server. and i'am checking the database entry's timestamps also. i can see the same time gap in the timestamps of each entry